# here are duplicate field(s) in fieldsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, field

This class raises a systems check django error. The specific error it raises is as pasted below. I have looked through previous posts that suggest it was an error that resulted from migrating to django 2.1 and adding a comma at the end of the fields tuple fixed it. This does not work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
<class 'app.admin.user.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[1][1]'.
<class 'app.admin.user.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[2][1]'.
<class 'app.admin.user.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E012) There are duplicate field(s) in 'fieldsets[3][1]'.

@register(User)
class UserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
        ('Personal info', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions',)}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined',)})
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2',),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups',)
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

Comment: You have the `email` field twice. Does removing one help?

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same error, although it seems that 'email' is unique in each tuple, it has to be unique in all tuples of 'fieldsets'.

> `(None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)})`

There you are saying that 'email' is a basic field and

> `('Personal info', {
>               'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)})`

is saying that 'email' is a 'Personal info' field. You have to choose.

Removing the second one is the solution, as @[Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As @Selcuk and @andramos have already suggested, you mentioned `'email'` twice. Look at your `fieldsets`:

The first one:

```
(None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
                     ^^^
```

and the second:

```
('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)}),
                                                           ^^^
```

In your case, removing `'email'` from `'Personal info'` will solve your issue:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
    ('Personal info', {
        'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                'groups', 'user_permissions',)}),
    ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined',)})
)
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2',),
    }),
)
```

There is a useful example in the [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) to customize user model, user forms and user admin.

For example, `MyUser` model is defined to use `email` field by preferred over `username`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```

In `admin.py` file:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **the same field "email" twice through all tuples in "fieldsets"** as shown below so you need to remove one of them:

```py
fieldsets = (              # Here
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password',)}),
        ('Personal info', {                       # Here
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions',)}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined',)})
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error and was able to solved it this way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from .models import User # My custom user model

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ["date_joined"]

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", 
                                        "last_name", 
                                        "email", # here I added my New 
                                        "image", # fields in custom User
                                        "gender", 
                                        "language"
                                        )}),
        (
            ("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).